# Error in the code when transferring data from a .csv file to DBeaver using Python

Tags: python, postgresql, dbeaver

I need to transfer data from a .csv file to DBeaver using Python. However, there are empty spaces in the data in the source data, so Python outputs an error about this. How do I rewrite the code so that the data from the .csv file is transferred completely, and there is no error?

`

```
`import csv
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="cars",
    user="students",
    password="qwerty"
)

cur = conn.cursor()

with open('region25.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # пропускаем заголовок
    for row in reader:
        try: 
            cur.execute(
                "INSERT INTO cars (brand, car_name, bodyType, color, fuelType, car_year, mileage, transmission, car_power, price, vehicleConfiguration, engineName, engineDisplacement, car_date, car_location, link, description, parse_date) "
                "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                row
            )
        except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e: 
            #print(f"Error:{e}. Row:{row}")

            print(row)

conn.commit()`
`
```

I used "try and except" function to fill gaps with .csv info, but data remained only in Python terminal.

Comment: by any chance, does `row` passed to your `curr.execute` need to be `tuple(row)`? If that does not help, can you give an example of the "bad" data?

Comment: psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type integer: ""
LINE 1: ...at', '124 Spider', 'Открытый', 'Синий', 'Бензин', '', '8000.... // This sentence contains '' which is "bad data" because there is just a "space" which does not belong to any of the data types like string or int.

Comment: 1) I am not seeing that this has anything to do with DBeaver, it is strictly `csv` --> `psycopg2` --> Postgres. 2) The error is correct `''` is not a valid string value for an integer: `select ''::integer; ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: ""`. 3) You need to either correct this in the CSV, by changing  `..,'',...` to `..,,...` or create a staging table that has all `varchar` fields and insert or copy into that. Then clean up the data and transfer to final table.

Comment: Instead of writing your own you might want to try the [copy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) statement or the psql variant `\copy`. They both already know how to handle empty columns.

Comment: @Belayer, `COPY/\copy` would  have the same issue and that it is it is not an empty column but a quoted empty string. And as I showed above;`select ''::integer; ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: ""`. If it where indeed empty `...,,...` then there would not be an issue as in CSV mode that would be taken as NULL, this assumes the column being filled accepts nulls.